# How to wait for tokio tasks to finish?

Tags: multithreading, rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to write to a `HashMap` using the `Arc<Mutex<T>>` pattern as part of a website scraping exercise inspired from [the Rust cookbook](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/web/scraping.html).

This first part uses `tokio` runtime. I cannot get past the tasks being completed and returning the `HashMap` as it just hangs.

```rust
type Db = Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, bool>>>;

pub async fn handle_async_tasks(db: Db) -> BoxResult<HashMap<String, bool>> {
    let links = NodeUrl::new("https://www.inverness-courier.co.uk/")
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let arc = db.clone();

    let mut handles = Vec::new();

    for link in links.links_with_paths {
        let x = arc.clone();
        handles.push(tokio::spawn(async move {
            process(x, link).await;
        }));
    }

    //  for handle in handles {
    //     handle.await.expect("Task panicked!");
    //  } < I tried this as well>

    futures::future::join_all(handles).await;

    let readables = arc.lock().await;

    for (key, value) in readables.clone().into_iter() {
        println!("Checking db: k, v ==>{} / {}", key, value);
    }

    let clone_db = readables.clone();

    return Ok(clone_db);
}

async fn process(db: Db, url: Url) {
    let mut db = db.lock().await;
    println!("checking {}", url);

    if check_link(&url).await.is_ok() {
        db.insert(url.to_string(), true);
    } else {
        db.insert(url.to_string(), false);
    }
}

async fn check_link(url: &Url) -> BoxResult<bool> {
    let res = reqwest::get(url.as_ref()).await?;
    Ok(res.status() != StatusCode::NOT_FOUND)
}

pub struct NodeUrl {
    domain: String,
    pub links_with_paths: Vec<Url>,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let db: Db = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));

    let db = futures::executor::block_on(task::handle_async_tasks(db));
}
```

I would like to return the `HashMap` to `main()` where the main thread is blocked. How can I wait for all async threaded processes to be complete and return the `HashMap`?

Comment: Can you provide your `main()` function? Otherwise no one can tell you how to use that `HashMap` in there

Comment: In addition to my answer I would suggest not jumping straight into `async` stuff without any prior Rust experience.

Comment: @orlp I updated my question with the actual url I was using and the `main()` function. @sebpuetz

Comment: @godhar What is `NodeUrl`?

Comment: @orlp it returns a Vec of URLs, with relative paths. It is working fine.

Comment: @orlp yes you are right, I jumped in too deep. But I struggle to let go at this point. If I can just print the hashmap with the links checked, I will be very satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

```rust
let links = NodeUrl::new("https://www.some-site.com/.co.uk/").await.unwrap();
```

This doesn't seem like a valid URL to me.

```rust
async fn process(db: Db, url: Url) {
    let mut db = db.lock().await;
    println!("checking {}", url);

    if check_link(&url).await.is_ok() {
         db.insert(url.to_string(), true);
    } else {
         db.insert(url.to_string(), false);
    }
}
```

This is highly problematic. You hold the exclusive lock on the database during the entire request. This makes your application effectively serial.
The default timeout in `reqwest` is 30 seconds. So if the server isn't responsive *and* you have a lot of links to go through the program might just seem to 'hang'.

You should only get the database lock for as short as possible - just to do the insert:

```rust
async fn process(db: Db, url: Url) {
    println!("checking {}", url);

    if check_link(&url).await.is_ok() {
         let mut db = db.lock().await;
         db.insert(url.to_string(), true);
    } else {
         let mut db = db.lock().await;
         db.insert(url.to_string(), false);
    }
}
```

Or even better, eliminating the useless if:

```rust
async fn process(db: Db, url: Url) {
    println!("checking {}", url);
    let valid = check_link(&url).await.is_ok();
    db.lock().await.insert(url.to_string(), valid);
}
```

Finally you didn't show your `main` function, the way you invoke `handle_async_tasks` or have other stuff running might be problematic.

Comment: I see your point about the lock open during the request. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

My main issue was how to handle the `MutexGuard` - which I did in the end by using `clone` and returning the inner value.

There was no need to use an `futures::executor`  in `main`: since we are within the tokio runtime, calling `.await` was sufficient to access the final value synchronously.

Cloning the `Arc` once was enough; I had cloned it twice before passing it into the multi-threaded context.

Thanks to @orlp for pointing out bad logic where it concerned the `check_link` function.

```rust
pub async fn handle_async_tasks() -> BoxResult<HashMap<String, bool>> {
    let get_links = NodeUrl::new("https://www.invernesscourier.co.uk/")
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let db: Db = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));
    let mut handles = Vec::new();

    for link in get_links.links_with_paths {
        let x = db.clone();

        handles.push(tokio::spawn(async move {
            process(x, link).await;
        }));
    }

    futures::future::join_all(handles).await;

    let guard = db.lock().await;
    let cloned = guard.clone();

    Ok(cloned)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let db = task::handle_async_tasks().await.unwrap();
    for (key, value) in db.into_iter() {
        println!("Checking db: {} / {}", key, value);
    }
}
```

This is by no means the best Rust code, but I wanted to share how I tackled things in the end.